# Sufficient condition for a polynomial to split

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I found a problem that reads: let $K\subseteq L$ be two fields, and consider an irreducible $f(x)$ in $K[x]$. Show that if there exists an $a\in L$ such that $a$ and $a^2$ are roots of $f$, then $f$ splits in $L$. Any hints?